# (visual c#) does not show my image

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, bitmap, load

I've got Visual Studio 2013 and I'm programming in c#.
I have this code, but it doesn't works:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Bitmap loader";
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        surface = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
        pictureBox1.Image = surface;

        device = Graphics.FromImage(surface);
        image = Properties.Resources.dragon;
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        device.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.dragon, 10, 10);
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

I had put [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/krlz532igk7iumz/dragon.bmp) image into resurce.
When I click run and it show me an empty window.

How can I achieve this screen showing my image?
(can anyone link my the zip of the progect???)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked just fine.

Make sure that the picturebox in the design editor has a size. 
Try to dock it to the parent container with the little arrow on the picturebox. There is also the option to set the scaling.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Bitmap loader";
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;

    this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dragon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've foudend the answer!!!
on the Form1() 
after the loadcompoents i must put this code

```
     this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load)
```

(it can't load Form1_load without it)